# First connection to REST with HttpClient takes long time

Tags: c#, .net-core

The first connection to our application server takes a long time.  It is taking from 4-9 seconds.  If I do the same call in Postman it takes 200-400ms.  If I keep the `HttpClient` in memory every other call returns speed like Postman.  Here is my code:

```
public static async Task<List<T>> Get(HttpClient client, string api)
{
    List<T> data = new List<T>();
    using var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(api);
    using var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    using var textReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader);
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    data = serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(textReader);
    return data;
}
```

The specific line of code that is taking so long is `using var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(api);`

This code is .Net Core 3.0.

Comment: Is it a TLS connection?

Comment: Side-point: no reason to pre-declare and initialize your `data` variable at the top of your method. Might as well `var data = serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(textReader);` or even just `return serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(textReader);`

Comment: I just googled "GetStreamAsync slow" and there is a lot of chatter about this, including some questions already here on Stack Overflow. Have a look! (Not going to mark this as a duplicate, but hopefully, this will help.)